# How can I write this SQL query

Tags: sql, reporting

I have a database table looks like this:

```
Group   -   Year  -      Value
-------------------------------
Group A     2018         200
Group A     2019         300
Group A     2020         400
Group B     2019         500
Group B     2020         300
```

I want to write a SQL query or something like that or a reporting tool to generate a report as below:

```
Group       2018     2019    2020
----------------------------------
Group A      200      300     400
Group B      ----     500     300
```

I tried different ways but still not sure how to do that? Anyone can help?

Comment: Syntax depends on your database. Please provide it. If you work with Postgresql, use 'crosstab' function, else 'Pivot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select group,
       sum(case when year = 2018 then value end) as value_2018,
       sum(case when year = 2019 then value end) as value_2019,
       sum(case when year = 2020 then value end) as value_2020
from t
group by group;
```

Note that `group` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.  If this is the actual name, I would suggest you change it.

Comment: Hi Gordon, you helped me on this before and that was very helpful. Now I need to do the conversion other way:

In case I have the table:

1. Group       2018     2019    2020
2. Group A      200      300     400
3. Group B      ----     500     300

I need to write a SQL query or something like that to generate a table like this:

1. Group   -   Year  -      Value
2. Group A     2018         200
3. Group A     2019         300
4. Group A     2020         400
5. Group B     2019         500
6. Group B     2020         300

Can you help? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Denis . . . You should ask this as a *new* question.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt comment, I asked this as a new question and the URL is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62648585/how-can-i-write-a-sql-query-to-conver-the-table-from-a-to-b . Thank you!